# Why is налогоплатЕльщик the correct form, and not налогоплатИльщик?

Tags: морфология

In most cases, we derive nouns in -щик from verbs. We observe the following pattern:

```
носить - носильщик
давить - давильщик
морить - морильщик
красить - красильщик
просить - просильщик
лудить - лудильщик
```

We also have платить. So why it is платЕльщик? That seems highly unnatural to me.

Answer (score 10):

This is the so-called "и - е swap" (*мена и - е*)

Trubachyov in *Труды по этимологии: Слово. История. Культура* attributes it to Russian glycolalia (*сладкоязычие*), which tends to mix stressed *ий* and *ль* in some dialects.

It's common to replace stressed *ий* with *ей* in Russian. That's why we have names like *Сергей, Мокей, Алексей* (from *Сергий, Мокий, Алексий*), words like *змей, книгочей* and the dialectal word *Расея*.

Glycolalia, among other things, causes stressed *иль* to be replaced by *ель* in some words by analogy with *ей < ий*:

- апрель < априль < Aprilis
- канитель < канетиль < cannetille

This contamination is most likely the cause of the swap in the word you cited above:

- плательщик (= платейщик) < платильщик (= платийщик)
- молельщик (= молейщик) < молильщик (= молийщик)

Comment: This does not explain why there is no such change in other words. Молельщик could change under analogy with болельщик.

Comment: @Anixx: what did *болельщик* change from? And yes, there are lots of words keeping the paradigm (all those mentioned in your example), it just happened so that those two did shift it.

Comment: болельщик is from болеть (not болить), so the e is substantiated here.

Comment: similarly радельщик from радеть

Comment: @Anixx: yes, all those words do obey the paradigm. What's your point?

Comment: the point is that when the verb has e the noun usually has e, when the verb has и the noun has и except in плательщик and молельщик (although the later could be from моление)

Comment: @Anixx - And also молельный and молебен.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe because  of *платеж* / *платежный*. Maybe if Russian had *платильный* and not *платежный*, it would be *платИльщик*.

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical aberration; when simplifications, dialect, parochialism, etc. invade the sphere of classical rules for particular language. "ПлатИльщик" is and must be recognized as the only correct option.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Russian.SE! Could you please clarify what exactly you mean by "must be recognized as the only correct option"? Thank you!